# firebase realtime database not responding

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: photo is here]

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../app settings/text sittings.dart';
import '../screens.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
 const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
 final namecontroller = TextEditingController();
 final emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
 final passwodconttroler = TextEditingController();
 final conformpasswodconttroler = TextEditingController();

 GlobalKey<FormState> formstate = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

 Future signUp() async {
   var formdata = formstate.currentState;
   if (formdata!.validate()) {
     formdata.save();
     if (passwordconfirmed()) {
       try {
         final User? credential =
             (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
           email: emailcontroller.text,
           password: passwodconttroler.text,
         ))
                 .user;
         return credential;
       } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
         if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
           AwesomeDialog(
               context: context,
               dialogType: DialogType.warning,
               animType: AnimType.bottomSlide,
               title: 'Week Password',
               body: const Text(
                 "The password is too weak",
               )).show();
         } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
           AwesomeDialog(
               context: context,
               dialogType: DialogType.warning,
               animType: AnimType.bottomSlide,
               title: 'Week Password',
               body: const Text(
                 "The account already exists for that email",
               )).show();
         }
         return null;
       } catch (e) {
         print(e);
       }
     }
   }
   if (signUp() != null) {
     DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("name");
     await ref.child("id").push().set({
       "id": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid,
       "name": namecontroller.text,
       "email": emailcontroller.text,
     });
   }
 }

 bool passwordconfirmed() {
   if (passwodconttroler.text.trim() == conformpasswodconttroler.text.trim()) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }

 void openSignScreen() {
   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignUpPage()));
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
   emailcontroller.dispose();
   passwodconttroler.dispose();
   conformpasswodconttroler.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
       body: SafeArea(
         child: ListView(children: [
           Stack(
             children: [
               Form(
                 key: formstate,
                 child: Column(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                   children: [
                     const SizedBox(
                       height: 150,
                       width: 60,
                     ),
                     const Text("Create Account",
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 40,
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                             fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                     const SizedBox(
                       height: 60,
                       width: 20,
                     ),
                     Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                           left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 20),
                       child: TextFormField(
                         validator: (value) {
                           if (value!.length > 20) {
                             return "Password is very long";
                           }
                           if (value.length < 7) {
                             return "Password is very short";
                           } else {
                             return null;
                           }
                         },
                         controller: namecontroller,
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                         textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                         decoration: InputDecoration(
                           hintText: "Full Name",
                           filled: true,
                           fillColor: Colors.white12,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                               borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                           left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 20),
                       child: TextFormField(
                         validator: (value) {
                           if (value!.length > 50) {
                             return "Password is very long";
                           }
                           if (value.length < 8) {
                             return "Password is very short";
                           } else {
                             return null;
                           }
                         },
                         controller: emailcontroller,
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                         textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                         decoration: InputDecoration(
                           hintText: "Email",
                           filled: true,
                           fillColor: Colors.white12,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                               borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                           left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 20),
                       child: TextFormField(
                         validator: (value) {
                           if (value!.length > 20) {
                             return "Password is very long";
                           }
                           if (value.length < 7) {
                             return "Password is very short";
                           } else {
                             return null;
                           }
                         },
                         controller: passwodconttroler,
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                         textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                         obscureText: true,
                         decoration: InputDecoration(
                           hintText: "Password",
                           filled: true,
                           fillColor: Colors.white12,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                               borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                           left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40),
                       child: TextFormField(
                         validator: (value) {
                           if (value!.length > 20) {
                             return "Password is very long";
                           }
                           if (value.length < 7) {
                             return "Password is very short";
                           } else {
                             return null;
                           }
                         },
                         controller: conformpasswodconttroler,
                         textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                         obscureText: true,
                         keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                         decoration: InputDecoration(
                           hintText: "Conform Password",
                           filled: true,
                           fillColor: Colors.white12,
                           border: OutlineInputBorder(
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                               borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     ElevatedButton(
                       onPressed: () {
                         if (signUp() == null) {
                           Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                               MaterialPageRoute(
                                   builder: (context) => const Screens()));
                         }
                       },
                       style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                         alignment: Alignment.center,
                         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                         ),
                         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                         maximumSize: const Size(300, 65),
                         minimumSize: const Size(300, 65),
                       ),
                       child: const DummyText(
                         text: "Sign Up",
                         size: 9,
                       ),
                     ),
                     const SizedBox(
                       height: 60,
                     )
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ]),
       ));
 }
}
```

and i made the realtime firebase rules true and I again downloaded the google.services.json and still it's not showing anything

**Please help me to solve this issue**

Comment: can u add ur permission rules screenshot

Comment: done up in the post

Comment: At a glance, this is the only code that accesses the database: `ref.child("id").push().set({...});`. Is that indeed the code. If so, going forward please reduce the amount of code we need to read by studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If that is indeed the only code accessing the database, can you try with hard-coded values like `ref.child("test").push().set(true);`? If that also doesn't work, it's likely something in the configuration or initialization.  If that write *does* work, it's more likely to be something in how you get the values from the UI.

Comment: Finally: this `if (signUp() != null) {` seems wrong, as `signUp` is an asynchronous function that returns a `Future`. Did you mean `if (await signUp() != null) {`?

Comment: thank you alot for this info and i'll work on it but how to solve my problem

Comment: yeah i think too if(signUp() != null) {....signUpCode...}seems wrong. U can do, after getting credential by signinUP u can add  signUpCode there...